# Can an app be built for distribution with iOS distribution certificates and provisioning profile, but without membership to the distribution account?

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution, provisioning, certificate

We have a freelancer developing an app for our company. We have a company iOS developer account, but the freelancer has been using his own account for development. The app is ready for distribution, but we would rather not give himaaccess or membership to our account. Is it possible to send him the distribution certificate/key and the distribution provisioning profile so that he can build the app and then send it to us for upload? If not, does anyone have suggestions for the best way to handle this?
Thanks!

Comment: Did this work? Mark the answer as correct if it did please, I'm trying to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you provide him with the developer certificate, developer key, and distribution certificate, he should be able to build the app for distribution with no problems.

Comment: Great! So he will need both the developer and distribution certificates then?

Comment: I don't think he needs the distribution certificates.  You only need it for distribution on AppStore.

Comment: Well, don't you want him to build it for distribution? Anyway, send him the distribution certificate that you built the app with, and then the developer certificate and key found in your keychain.